# Prove there exists $a\neq b$ in $[0,1]$ such that $|f(a)-f(b)|=|a-b|^{100}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be continuous function and non-constant. Then there exists $a\neq b$ in $[0,1]$ such that $|f(a)-f(b)|=|a-b|^{100}$. I have no idea to check this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: First, if $|f(b)-f(a)|\le|a-b|^{100}$  for all $a\ne b$ then $f'=0$ so $f$ is constant. So there exist $a_1,b_1$ with $|f(a_1)-f(b_1)| > |a_1-b_1|^{100}$.

And if $|f(a)-f(b)|\ge|a-b|^{100}$ for all $a\ne b$ then $|f(0)-f(1)|=|0-1|^{100}$ and you're done.  So you can assume there exist $a_2,b_2$ with $|f(a_2)-f(b_2)|<|a_2-b_2|^{100}$.

Now by symmetry you can also assume $a_1<b_1$ and $a_2<b_2$. Hence there exist $a,b$ with $a\ne b$ and $|f(a)-f(b)|=|a-b|^{100}$, because... (Given $<$ at one point and $>$ at another point it's clear by ... that you have equality at some point. But if $a_1-b_1$ and $a_2-b_2$ have different signs that might not help because ...)

Answer (score 1):

Let $U=\{(a,b)\in [0,1]^2: b>a\}.$ Then $U$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb R^2.$ Define $g: U\to [0,\infty)$ by setting

$$g(a,b) = \frac{|f(b)-f(a)|}{(b-a)^{100}}.$$

Then $g$ is continuous on $U.$ Thus $g(U)$ is connected.

Now, as D. Ullrich mentioned, we have $g>1$ somewhere in $U$ because $f$ is nonconstant. So by connectivity, all we need to show is that $g\le 1$ somewhere in $U.$ Since $g(0,1) \le 1/(1-0)^{100} = 1,$ we're done.